# Cannot specify enumeration label in Frontiers style

Tags: enumerate, enumitem

I am using the [Frontiers style](http://www.frontiersin.org/design/zip/Frontiers_LaTeX_Templates.zip) (`FrontiersSCNS.cls`) and could not find a way to change the enumeration label. In all other styles, I could easily do something like this:

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
  \item this is the first item,
  \item this is the second item
\end{enumerate}
```

But with this style, no matter what I select it always produces the `\arabic*` format. this question is specific to this style and I believe somewhere anything I do is being overwritten.

A working example for testing:

```
\documentclass[utf8]{frontiersSCNS}
\usepackage{url,hyperref,lineno,microtype}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

\linenumbers
\def\keyFont{\fontsize{8}{11}\helveticabold }
\def\firstAuthorLast{X {et~al.}} 


\begin{document}
\onecolumn
\firstpage{1}

\title[Title]
\maketitle

\section{Section 1}
\begin{enumerate}%[label=(\alph*)]
  \item first item
  \item second item
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

What I have tried:

1. adding `\usepackage{enumitem}` in the `cls` file produces the following error: `Latex Error: Environment description undefined`
2. Something like this also did not had any effect:

   ```
   \setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\textit{\alph*)}}
   \usepackage{enumerate}
   ```

Answer (score 1):

It seems this class is incompatible with `enummitem` … because it defines no`description` environment.

Two work-arounds: either you load `enumerate` and use its syntax to modify the label, or you redefine the label by hand, with:

```
\renewcommand\labelenumi{(\alph{enumi})}
```

Here is a code with the first solution:

```
\documentclass[utf8]{frontiersSCNS}
\usepackage{url,hyperref,lineno,microtype}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{enumerate} 
\linenumbers
\def\keyFont{\fontsize{8}{11}\helveticabold }
\def\firstAuthorLast{X {et~al.}}


\begin{document}
\onecolumn
\firstpage{1}

\title[Title]
\maketitle

\section{Section 1}
\begin{enumerate}[(a) ]
  \item first item
  \item second item
\end{enumerate}

\end{document
```

[image]

*Edit*:

Following a suggestion of Phelype Oleinik, we can load  `enumitem` with this class, defining an empty description environment first. Here is an example code which yields the same result as above:

```
\documentclass[utf8]{frontiersSCNS}
\usepackage{url,hyperref,lineno,microtype}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

\newenvironment{description}{}{}
\usepackage{enumitem} 

\linenumbers
\def\keyFont{\fontsize{8}{11}\helveticabold }
\def\firstAuthorLast{X {et~al.}}

\begin{document}
\onecolumn
\firstpage{1}

\title[Title]
\maketitle
\section{Section 1}
\begin{enumerate}[label = (\alph*), wide = 0pt, leftmargin =* ]%[(a) ]
  \item first item
  \item second item
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe you could `\def\description{}` before loading `enumitem`. The output looks strange though...

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik: I've made an edit to follow your idea and use `enumitem`. However I had to specify some more parameters to obtain an acceptable result.